# Transform a simple table to a color coded table

Tags: python, excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting

I've a table that looks like:

[image: SO29524725 first question example]

I want to transform the table into something like:

[image: SO29524725 second question example]

I did some thinking, but couldn't think of anything fruitful.

How can I do this in MS-Excel or any programming software like Python?

Comment: added the snapshot, does that help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `1` in your table is in G1, and that the output will be in A1:E5, please select that range and fill it red. Then with the same selection HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cell to format*, **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
 =MATCH(CHAR(COLUMN()+96),$H1:$J1,0)>0
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select Fill green, OK, OK.

[image: SO2524725 example]

I have assumed that the Headings are adequate as row and column labels.